# passes variable to table but cannot use it before

Tags: php

I got the following piece of code in php:

I have a page called post.php which posts successfully all data using jquery. The data that it posts are: $comments_id, $reply and $the_session_user_id as you  can see in my code and I can get them successfully. My problem is that my equation **if($session_user_id ==  $the_session_user_id )** is not working. It is like it cannot get **$the_session_user_id**. How can this be possible, since next it pass it to the table using the mysql statement? If I delete the **if($session_user_id ==  $the_session_user_id )** and not make this choice, it passes succesfully all data to table. Any idea why my if statement not working?

```
<?php

// $session_user_id is the user id of the session

// the following data posted from a page called post.php wich posts them using jquery succesfully


    $comments_id = $_POST['data_comments_id'];

    $reply = $_POST['data_reply'];

    $the_session_user_id =  $_POST['data_session_user_id'];  

if(isset($reply) && !empty($reply)){ 

        if($session_user_id ==  $the_session_user_id ){ 

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments_reply VALUES ('', '$comments_id', '$reply', now(), '', '$the_session_user_id') "); 
        }else{
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments_reply VALUES ('', '$comments_id', '$reply', now(), '1', '$the_session_user_id') "); 
        }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems like `$session_user_id` isn't declared/assigned any value. `$session_user_id` will therefore be 'null'. You must first assign your `$_SESSION['your_id_key']` to $session_user_id: `$session_user_id = $_SESSION['your_id_key']`

You can try to echo both values (`$session_user_id` and `$the_session_user_id`) before the if to see wich value they've got assigned:

`echo $session_user_id;
echo $the_session_user_id;`